# Screen.AllScreens does not change when connecting by RDP

Tags: wpf, winforms, screen, remote-desktop, rdp

I have a desktop PC with a 2560 x 1440 resolution, and a netbook with a 1024 x 600 resolution.

When I RDP-connect with the netbook to the desktop, the screen of the desktop is presented in 1024x600, since the netbook does not allow more. So, there is some re-scaling of the windows, and some kind of 'virtual screen' just changed its size from 2560x1440 to 1024x600.

However, the `System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens` property does not reflect this change, its single array item stays at 2560 x 1440.

How can I detect the 'virtual screen size change' in .NET, using WinForms or WPF?

Thank you

**Edit:**

I forgot to say, the `AllScreens` property changes its value when I debug in Visual Studio (with the vshost.exe host EXE), but as soon as I run the program without a debugger, the `AllScreens` property does not reflect the change in screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to detect screen resolution changes from both the desktop computer and from a remote laptop connecting through remote desktop as well as having it report the proper resolution numbers by the following technique:

I just created a sample WinForms program that handles this event:

```
Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += 
     SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged;
```

In my test I had a listbox which displayed the information when the screen changed:

```
void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var screen in System.Windows.Forms.Screen.AllScreens)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add("Device Name: " + screen.DeviceName);
        listBox1.Items.Add("Bounds: " +
            screen.Bounds.ToString());
        listBox1.Items.Add("Type: " +
            screen.GetType().ToString());
        listBox1.Items.Add("Working Area: " +
            screen.WorkingArea.ToString());
        listBox1.Items.Add("Primary Screen: " +
            screen.Primary.ToString());
    }
}
```

I ran the program in release mode outside the debugger on my desktop and then connected from my lower resolution laptop and the numbers changed to reflect the lower resolution.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone wants to do the same in PowerShell, this code does basically the same as Brad Rem's code, only saving results to a TextBox:

```
[Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents]::add_DisplaySettingsChanged({
    $AppendText = ''
    foreach ($Screen in [Screen]::AllScreens) {
        $InfoTextBox.Text +=  $AppendText +
            "Device Name: $($Screen.DeviceName)`r`n" +
            "Bounds: $($Screen.Bounds.ToString())`r`n" +
            "Type: $($Screen.GetType().ToString())`r`n" +
            "Working Area: $($Screen.WorkingArea.ToString())`r`n" +
            "Primary Screen: $($Screen.Primary.ToString())`r`n"
        $AppendText = "&`r`n"
    }
    $InfoTextBox.Text += "`r`n"
})
```

The following results were in a Windows 10 environment for both the remote computer and the local computer.

Results when remoting into a multi-monitor computer that is already logged on, and then braking the RDP-connection by sitting down at the computer and un-locking it:

```
Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY49
Bounds: {X=0,Y=0,Width=1280,Height=1024}
Type: System.Windows.Forms.Screen
Working Area: {X=0,Y=0,Width=1280,Height=1024}
Primary Screen: True

Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY1
Bounds: {X=0,Y=0,Width=2560,Height=1440}
Type: System.Windows.Forms.Screen
Working Area: {X=0,Y=0,Width=2560,Height=1440}
Primary Screen: True
&
Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY2
Bounds: {X=-1200,Y=0,Width=1200,Height=1920}
Type: System.Windows.Forms.Screen
Working Area: {X=-1200,Y=0,Width=1200,Height=1920}
Primary Screen: False
```

Results from removing a monitor and plugging it back in:

```
Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY2
Bounds: {X=0,Y=0,Width=1200,Height=1920}
Type: System.Windows.Forms.Screen
Working Area: {X=0,Y=0,Width=1200,Height=1920}
Primary Screen: True

Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY1
Bounds: {X=0,Y=0,Width=2560,Height=1440}
Type: System.Windows.Forms.Screen
Working Area: {X=0,Y=0,Width=2560,Height=1440}
Primary Screen: True
&
Device Name: \\.\DISPLAY2
Bounds: {X=-1200,Y=0,Width=1200,Height=1920}
Type: System.Windows.Forms.Screen
Working Area: {X=-1200,Y=0,Width=1200,Height=1920}
Primary Screen: False
```